# saveFileDialog create new folder and save inside it

Tags: c#, savefiledialog

i wanna create backup data in my application I used saveFileDialog, so i can place backup file anywhere i want (Dekstop, drive D, etc)

my backup file will be db, image, video so i guess it's will be easier to place that in one folder let say it's "myBackup" folder (generate automatically with C#)
so if user wanna save in Dekstop all of backup data will be in ~C:\Users\Maju\Desktop\myBackup~

i already successfully generate folder but my file won't save inside that

```
mySaveFileDialog.FileName = "Backup Database " + dateTimeNow;

if (mySaveFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    string fileAsal = System.IO.Path.Combine(Global.myDatabaseLocation, "data.mdb");

    FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(mySaveFileDialog.FileName);
    string nameFolder = "myBackup";
    System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(@fi.DirectoryName + "\\" + nameFolder);

    string path = System.IO.Path.Combine (fi.DirectoryName, "\\" + nameFolder);
    string pathDestination = System.IO.Path.Combine(path, mySaveFileDialog.FileName);
    System.IO.File.Copy(fileAsal, pathDestination, true);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Is not it easier to use FolderBrowserDialog?
2. mySaveFileDialog.FileName already includes the path to the file so you need to write

   ```
   string pathDestination = System.IO.Path.Combine(path, System.IO.Path.GetFileName(mySaveFileDialog.FileName));
   ```

Comment: 1. you are right, i think it's easier to use folderBrowseDialog....thanks for suggesting that

Comment: 2. i try u modify script but it's no work..when i messageBox pathDestination it's just display (namefolder and mySaveFileDialog.nameFile)...it's seem the path lost (C:\Users\Maju\Desktop)

Comment: Don't use FileInfo. Change to code to use var outDirName = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(mySaveDialog.FileName, nameFolder); Directory.Create(outDirName); File.Copy(fileAsal, Path.Combine(outDirName, Path.GetFileName(mySaveDialog.FileName), true);

Comment: does that scipt work in framework 4.0
because i get many error, like overload method GetDirectoryName can't take 2 argument, system IO does not contain definiton for 'Create'

Comment: Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(mySaveDialog.FileName), nameFolder);